# Use /etc/hosts to direct wildcard domain name

Tags: server, dns, hosts

I searched this term and didn't find my answer: "wildcard domain name in hosts"

I have a HostGator account where I create secret domains so I can build and test websites.  In order to use them, I add the domain to my /etc/hosts file like:

```
192.168.129.3 ts.buck
192.168.129.3 www.ts.buck
```

I tried using the *

```
192.168.129.3 *.buck
```

but it doesn't work.

This is on my desktop, I don't have a server here. It is also for internal use only, not for the rest of the world to see or access.

It would be nice to have a simple way to use my own TLD for building test sites.

Comment: Really? http://serverfault.com/questions/118378/in-my-etc-hosts-file-on-linux-osx-how-do-i-do-a-wildcard-subdomain http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/wildcard-in-etc-hosts-file  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446930/how-to-put-wildcard-entry-into-etc-hosts

Comment: You could have made an answer and I would have upvoted you ;)

Comment: Should I have clarified that I searched "askubuntu"?

Comment: explain why the negative?

Comment: here I put it back to 0 ;-) and to the 1st comment: probably, That 1st line can tick people the wrong way when they find a results within seconds ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set up a DNS server. (install [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) (is light) or [bind](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/358) (is rather heavy)). To install ...

```
 sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

In `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq-localhost.conf`

add

```
 address=/localhost.com/127.0.0.1
```

restart

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

**Important note**.

If `dnsmasq` service failed to start, please check your service logs by running `systemctl status dnsmasq.service` command.

Then, If you will see the following message in the logs `Failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use` - you may resolve this error as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358485)

Comment: This was a very easy fix and very simple answer.  Much better than the pages in the links.  I wish I had asked this years ago.

Comment: I added the line:

address=/.buck/192.168.129.3 

to dnsmasq-localhost.conf.  

This did the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't mean to override your answer, just clarify the added line without editing your answer.  

WOW, I am happy.

Comment: Oh you are welcome to edit anything important into this answer ;-)

Comment: @Buck As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know how to do that.  Thank you and Bless You!

Comment: `sudo service network-manager restart` : make sure to restart the network manager too :)

Comment: For Ubuntu 16 use this to restart network manager `sudo  systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`

Comment: I dont have the `dnsmasq.d/` directory after the `apt-get`. The only thing I have under `NetworkManager` is `dispatcher.d/hook-network-manager`. Should I manually create that folder and file?  (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Do I need to add something to my /etc/hosts file?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029882/how-can-i-set-up-local-wildcard-127-0-0-1-domain-resolution-on-18-04-20-04

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick addition to the above answer, make sure that your local domain name DOES NOT end with `.local`, it looks like this is a reserved name so in your `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
address=/somesite.local/127.0.0.1
```

WILL NOT WORK

```
address=/somesite.loc/127.0.0.1
```

will work.

Comment: If you have an addition to that answer, suggest an edit: https://askubuntu.com/posts/743051/edit

Comment: Also "above answer" can become irrelevant after a while