# How can I set up local wildcard (127.0.0.1) domain resolution on 18.04..20.04?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, dns, dnsmasq

On Ubuntu 14.04 I'm using dnsmasq to resolve wildcard example.com domains to the local machine (desktop computer at home).

After much reading around I cannot for the life of me sort out the same on a clean install of 18.04.

All I want to achieve at the moment is:

- for `ping example.com`
  to ping 127.0.0.1 and not 93.184.216.34;
- for `ping anysubdomain.example.com`
  to also ping 127.0.0.1;
- and for `ping google.com`
  to ping the real google.com via the router/IP DNS.

Surely this must be simple, even trivial?

But I'm stumped. I can get the example.com's resolving but only at the expense of breaking everything else.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just install dnsmasq like you did on 14.04?

Comment: @vidarlo Well of course that was the first thing I did, as I indicated in my question. But unlike in 14.04 that results in a "failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use" error. The answer I accepted works fine without installing dnsmasq explicitly.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here are the steps for ubuntu since 18.04. It's a little bit long since `systemd-resolved` does not play very well with `NetworkManager` when configured with `dnsmasq`.

Yet I still recommend starting `dnsmasq` from `NetworkManager`, because network connectivity changes (WIFI, wired, ...) will be handled transparently.

**Enable dnsmasq in NetworkManager**

Edit the file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, and add the line `dns=dnsmasq` to the `[main]` section, it will look like this :

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

**Let NetworkManager manage `/etc/resolv.conf`**

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf ; sudo ln -s /var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

**Configure `example.com`**

```
echo 'address=/.example.com/127.0.0.1' | sudo tee /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/example.com-wildcard.conf
```

**Reload `NetworkManager` and testing**

NetworkManager should be reloaded for the changes to take effect.

```
sudo systemctl reload NetworkManager
```

Then we can verify that we can reach some usual site :

```
dig askubuntu.com +short
151.101.129.69
151.101.65.69
151.101.1.69
151.101.193.69
```

And lastly verify that the `example.com` and subdomains are resolved as `127.0.0.1`:

```
dig example.com askubuntu.example.com a.b.c.d.example.com +short
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: what do you mean with "systemd-resolved does not play very well with NetworkManager"?

Comment: When NetworkManager uses dns=dnsmasq, it should tell systemd-resolved to use dnsmasq, could be automatic.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! It seems I can't give you the bounty for another hour, and as it's gone one in the morning here I'm off to bed now and will do that when I switch back on tomorrow.

Comment: Awesome. I've read many different techniques. This is the one that finally worked.

Comment: For those who prefer to revert back to systemd-resolved, `/etc/resolv.conf` points to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` by default.

Comment: The only solution working as of 2019.03.

Comment: It can be useful
echo 'address=/.loc/127.0.0.1' | sudo tee /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/loc-wildcard.conf

Comment: Works as of September 2nd, 2019 - UBuntu 19.04

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04 as well

Comment: I could not get this to work in January 2021 on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Can I use `*` or `?` like this: `server=/*-api.some-dev.com/192.168.1.5`?

Comment: Works, Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 2):

First make sure in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` the following line is **not** present or commented out:

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

Restart NetworkManager:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Make sure the NetworkManager-controlled dnsmasq is not running anymore, either by killing the process or rebooting your system.

Then install dnsmasq:

```
sudo apt install dnsmasq
```

Add the following to `/etc/dnsmasq.d/example.com`:

```
address=/example.com/127.0.0.1
```

Restart dnsmasq:

```
sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq
```

Now you should have a wildcard dns override for example.com.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. Immediately following a clean minimal install (with the "erase disk" option) the `sudo apt install dnsmasq` gives a "failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use" error. I continued to the end anyway in case a later step resolved that, but it didn't and this didn't work.

Comment: Then the dnsmasq that is started by NetworkManager was still running. So it should first be deactivated, eventually killed, and only then the dnsmasq package should be installed.

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian. However I already accepted pim's answer which worked flawlessly, so I'm able to move on now without playing around with it any more.

Comment: @NickRice No problem with this, but maybe others want to try

Comment: Yes of course, Sebastian. I did try your answer first because it was the simplest, and if all it needs is an added initial step then it's a very good one.

Comment: Looking at your edit, /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf did not have any mention of dnsmasq in it to start with, out of the box, and so there was nothing to change and restarting NetworkManager could make no difference. Did you mean to that `dns=dnsmasq` *should* be put in as per the accepted answer? If so, best change the bit that says to ensure it is **not** present to saying to ensure it **is** present.

Comment: You could have NetworkManager control dnsmasq or not, that is what this line is about. In my answer I propose to have it not controlled by nm so you as a user have full control over it. This line might be present or not, depending on what the user has tried before or if they upgraded from some version that had it activated.

Comment: As I put in the question, it was a completely clean install, so no previous history or anything else left over from a previous OS etc, and each thing I tried I went back to a fresh install. But moving on now.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [pim's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029882/how-can-i-set-up-local-wildcard-127-0-0-1-domain-resolution-on-18-04-20-04/1031896#1031896), I have created a gist containing a simple Bash script which uses DNSMasq in combination with NetworkManager to setup the .test domain pointing to 127.0.0.1

See the gist at https://gist.github.com/archan937/d35deef3b1f2b5522dd4b8f397038d27.

You can execute the script with the following command:

```
curl -sL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/archan937/d35deef3b1f2b5522dd4b8f397038d27/raw/setup-dnsmasq.sh | sudo bash
```

Cheers!

Comment: This is awesome, but it doesn't work for me. It just ends up with could not ping foo.test

Comment: Hey, @SimaPro. I increased the ping timeout to 1 second. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: Successful after I forked + updated the service restart syntax (for Ubuntu 22.04)

Answer (score 0):

This won't be as simple as editing the hosts file. You have a couple of options:

[This python DNS proxy](https://github.com/hubdotcom/marlon-tools/blob/master/tools/dnsproxy/dnsproxy.py) that will handle wildcards in /etc/hosts

[Using DNSmasq](https://serverfault.com/a/118589)

Comment: Thanks. Your link to the DNSmasq question is what I am doing in 14.04. Just doing the same in a fresh 18.04 installation isn't working due to a port conflict. So out of the box something else needs doing compared to that. Looking at all that code needed for the python DNS proxy, I can't believe all that is necessary. It wasn't before except, I suppose, for those who insisted on using /etc/hosts.

Comment: Can you do `netstat -tulpn` to check what's using the port?
EDIT: Nevermind, saw the accepted answer. the problem is systemd-resolve.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `dnsmasq-base` that is already pre-installed in Ubuntu instead of `dnsmasq` for the same purpose.

So don't install `dnsmasq` but do all steps from here https://askubuntu.com/a/1031896/211368

If you install `dnsmasq` it will collide with already running `dnsmasq-base` and you'll get an error:
`failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use`