# how to set up dnsmasq wildcard to 127.0.0.1 on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: dnsmasq

closely related to [How can I set up local wildcard (127.0.0.1) domain resolution on 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029882/how-can-i-set-up-local-wildcard-127-0-0-1-domain-resolution-on-18-04) .  here is what I have done, following the earlier 18.04 instructions on 19.10:

1. Installed dnsmasq

```
apt install dnsmasq
```

2. edited NetworkManager.conf

```
# head -3 /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq
```

(This appears not to work [add dns=dnsmasq later to resolv.conf.)

3.

```
# sudo ln -sf /var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
# ls -l /etc/resolv.conf                         
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 35 Oct 18 20:59 /etc/resolv.conf -> /var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
```

4. created a few rules

```
# more /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/*    
::::::::::::::
/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq-localhost.conf
::::::::::::::
address=/localhost.com/127.0.0.1
::::::::::::::
/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/dotlocal-wildcard.conf
::::::::::::::
address=/.local/127.0.0.1
::::::::::::::
/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/example.com-wildcard.conf
::::::::::::::
address=/.example.com/127.0.0.1
```

5. made sure to run dnsmasq and reloaded

```
systemctl disable systemd-resolved
systemctl stop systemd-resolved
systemctl start dnsmasq
systemctl reload NetworkManager
```

6. checked who is listening

```
# sudo netstat -tulpn | grep dns
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      949/dnsmasq         
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      949/dnsmasq         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           949/dnsmasq         
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                949/dnsmasq
```

7. and observed my failure

```
# dig example.com +short
93.184.216.34
# dig example.local +short
# host example.local       
Host example.local not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

---

Problem 1
: should step 3 have not made `resolv.conf` somehow acquire a `dns=dnsmask` or (`nameserver 127.0.0.1`) to query?  if I add these by hand into `resolve.conf`, I can (sometimes) resolve `example.com` and `any.example.com` to the desired 127.0.0.1.

Problem 2
: why does even then 'example.local' not resolve, as desired, to 127.0.0.1?

advice appreciated.

PS: What a pity that wildcard matching to 127.0.0.1 is not part of standard resolved, and instead requires dnsmasq.

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029882/how-can-i-set-up-local-wildcard-127-0-0-1-domain-resolution-on-18-04-20-04

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this as the top line in the `resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

And also try installing `named`.